# plot the locus of points whose squared distance from the origin is $1$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Plotting the locus of points equidistant from a point](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/201958/plotting-the-locus-of-points-equidistant-from-a-point)

I'm trying to solve this question, I encountered whiles reading a multivariate analysis book and i need assistance. An explaination will do. "Define the distance from $ P(x_{1}, x_{2})$ to the origin as $ d(O,P) = max(|x_{1}|,|x_{2}|)$. I'm done with the first part of the question. I'm to plot the locus of points whose squared distance from the origin is $1$. "

Comment: @ Nicholas, I have updated it.

Comment: Now it is exactly like the [previous problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/201958/plotting-the-locus-of-points-equidistant-from-a-point) posted today.

Comment: @AndréNicolas:  but close enough that I vote it a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

If the squared distance is 1, then the distance is 1. So you're looking to plot the points $(x,y)$ where $\max(|x|,|y|)=1$ (I'm assuming you meant $|x_1|,|x_2|$ where you wrote $|x_1,x_2|$, since I can't make any sense out of the latter). So, can you do that?